# Create a string based on a case selection in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, do-while

I am brand new to coding and I am re-creating the start of a Pokemon game in order to practice. I am using the 'while' with cases and I currently have this (please note I have created a method for TypeLine to print the text but a character at a time like dialogue rather than the full sentence all at once. This code is working so ignore that and imagine it as Console.WriteLine);

```
//Player makes their Pokemon choice.
            bool pokemonChoice = true;

            while (pokemonChoice)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                int key = Convert.ToInt32(input);

                switch (key)
                {
                    case 1:
                        TypeLine("\nCharmander! What an excellent decision! \n");
                        TypeLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED CHARMANDER! \n");
                        pokemonChoice = false;
                        break;
                       

                    case 2:
                        TypeLine("\nSquirtle! What an excellent decision! \n");
                        TypeLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED SQUIRTLE! \n");
                        pokemonChoice = false;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        TypeLine("\nBulbasaur! What an excellent decision! \n");
                        TypeLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED BULBASAUR! \n");
                        pokemonChoice = false;
                        break;
```

What I want to do, is if say case 1 is selected by the user inputting "1", then a new string is created called "pokemon" and is assigned "Charmander".

```
string pokemon = ("Charmander");
```

The purpose is so that later, instead of having to type the Pokemon name, I could use;

```
Console.WriteLine(pokemon + " I choose you!");
```

I attempted to do so in the case itself, like this;

```
                switch (key)
                {
                    case 1:
                        string pokemon = ("Charmander");
                        TypeLine("\nCharmander! What an excellent decision! \n");
                        TypeLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED CHARMANDER! \n");
                        pokemonChoice = false;
                        break;
```

But when I then try to use it outside of the 'while', I get the error "The name 'pokemon' does not exist in the current context"

How can I achieve the result I have detailed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Declare your string before the switch block, not inside.

Comment: This is a problem of [variable scope](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp) and you now have a good opportunity to learn about this important concept!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't *get access* to your `pokemon` string because it is declared inside your `switch` loop, and cant be *accessed* anywhere outside of it. Basically, it *lives* and *dies* inside that scope.

So, create that same variable in the start of your program, or outside of your function, and you will be able to use it whenever you wish.

Maybe consider some time [reading](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/variable-scope) about this ocassion.

Here is the actual code, note that `string pokemon = ""` is used like a workaround for an *Use of unassigned local variable 'pokemon'* error. Simply put any value at start. (For `int` variables we usually do `int smth = 0`)

```
bool pokemonChoice = true;
        
        string pokemon = ""; 
        while (pokemonChoice)
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            int key = Convert.ToInt32(input);
            switch (key)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nCharmander! What an excellent decision! \n");
                    Console.WriteLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED CHARMANDER! \n");
                    pokemon = "Charmander"; //assign the value if the case 1 is picked
                    pokemonChoice = false;
                    break;
                   

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nSquirtle! What an excellent decision! \n");
                    Console.WriteLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED SQUIRTLE! \n");
                    pokemon = "Squirtle"; //assign the value if the case 2 is picked
                    pokemonChoice = false;
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("\nBulbasaur! What an excellent decision! \n");
                    Console.WriteLine("CONGRATULATIONS! YOU JUST OBTAINED BULBASAUR! \n");
                    pokemon = "Bulbasaur"; //assign the value if the case 3 is picked
                    pokemonChoice = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("The chosen pokemon is - " + pokemon);
```

Comment: I see, thanks for explaining. 

Now I have declared ```string pokemon;``` outside of the switch loop, how do I assign its value based on the selection inside the switch loop if it is isolated?

Comment: @WolfPG Can there be multiple cases picked? I mean, can the user choose many times, and gather, for example, both Charmander, and Pikachu?

Comment: @WolfPG You should just be able to assign it, just like you do with `pokemonChoice`. Scope is hierarchical, so a block or function can access the scope outside of it, just not the other way around.

Comment: @aca only one case can be chosen in this scenario. So if case 1 (Charmander) is chosen then I would want ```string pokemon;``` to be assigned the value "Charmander".

Comment: @WolfPG In that scenario, simply put `pokemon = "Charmander"`   in case 1, and like so in every other case, with name that you need, for example in case 2 `pokemon = "Pikachu" ` etc. By doing that, the value that `string pokemon` gets will be the value you set in chosen case, and you can use that same variable afterwards to print what you need.

Comment: @aca Thanks, that makes sense. I have tried this but I get the error that 'pokemon' is an un-assigned local variable.

I have added ```string pokemon;``` outside of the loop, and then inside I have added ```pokemon = "Charmander";``` under case 1. Then, after the loop I have added ```Console.WriteLine(pokemon);```

Error received "Use of unassigned local variable 'pokemon'"

Comment: @WolfPG Wait, I'll post the whole code up in the answer. It's kid of hectic doing things like this.

Comment: @aca much appreciated, thank you. I'm only a week into learning coding. I feel i'm making good progress but practice makes perfect. Plus being able to see the whole code helps me read it and understand it. I'm not quite good enough to understand how short slices of code fit into the bigger piece yet.

Comment: @WolfPG It's updated. I completely understand you, and I feel like you are on the right way. Keep up with the good work.

Comment: @aca that worked! Thank you so much. And I will definitely keep up with it. I've told myself it will get super difficult at some point but if I just keep repeating the lessons and reading etc then it will eventually click.